# In PySpark, get filled column and put in another dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to input data from dataframe (A) to dataframe (B), where A has many rows with the same Id. So It's necessary to identify which column is filled in the dataframe A and put in the dataframe B. How can I do this using PySpark-SQL?

Dataframe A:

```
+------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|ID                                  |NAME    |PHONE   |ADDRESS |
+------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|bd46c6fb-1315-4418-9943-2e7d3151f788|null    |null    |Street 1|
|d2636151-b95e-4845-8014-0a113c381ff9|null    |null    |null    |
|bd46c6fb-1315-4418-9943-2e7d3151f788|JOHN DOE|null    |null    |
|d2636151-b95e-4845-8014-0a113c381ff9|null    |17888849|null    |
+------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Dataframe B:

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+
|ID                                  |MSG_DT                  |RECEIVE|SEND               |
+------------------------------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+
|d2636151-b95e-4845-8014-0a113c381ff9|2022-08-07T21:24:54.552Z|Oi     |Olá!               |
|4241224b-9ba5-4eda-8e16-7e3aeaacf164|2022-08-07T21:25:06.565Z|4      |Certo              |
|bd46c6fb-1315-4418-9943-2e7d3151f788|2022-08-07T21:25:30.408Z|1      |⭐️*Antes de você ir |
|14da8519-6e4c-4edc-88ea-e33c14533dd9|2022-08-07T21:25:52.798Z|788884 |Agora              |
+------------------------------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+
```

Result:

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|ID                                  |MSG_DT                  |RECEIVE|SEND               |NAME    |PHONE   |ADDRESS |
+------------------------------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|d2636151-b95e-4845-8014-0a113c381ff9|2022-08-07T21:24:54.552Z|Oi     |Olá!               |null    |17888849|null    |
|4241224b-9ba5-4eda-8e16-7e3aeaacf164|2022-08-07T21:25:06.565Z|4      |Certo              |null    |null    |null    |
|bd46c6fb-1315-4418-9943-2e7d3151f788|2022-08-07T21:25:30.408Z|1      |⭐️*Antes de você ir|JOHN DOE|null    |Street 1|  
|14da8519-6e4c-4edc-88ea-e33c14533dd9|2022-08-07T21:25:52.798Z|788884 |Agora              |null    |null    |null    |
+------------------------------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: DataFrame B and the result DataFrame are the same.

Comment: *"where A has many rows with the same Id. So It's necessary to identify which column is filled in the dataframe A"* can you share examples of such cases, and point them out?

Comment: also, can there be cases where an ID has 2 different non-null values in the same column (instead of 1 null and 1 non-null)? if yes, how do you want to handle them?

Answer (score 0):

You can [group](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) `dataframe A` by ID and use [first](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#first) as aggregation function. By setting the `isIgnoreNull` parameter the `null` values will be ignored. Please note that the outcome of this grouping operation is non-deterministic if there is more than one non-null value per `ID` and column.

Finally the grouped data is [joined](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) to `dataframe B` using a left outer join:

```python
df_b.join( 
  df_a.groupBy("ID").agg(f.first("NAME", True), f.first("PHONE", True), f.first("ADDRESS", True)),
  on="ID", 
  how="leftouter") \
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|                  ID|              MSG_DT|RECEIVE|         SEND|first(NAME)|first(PHONE)|first(ADDRESS)|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|d2636151-b95e-484...|2022-08-07T21:24:...|     Oi|         Olá!|       null|    17888849|          null|
|4241224b-9ba5-4ed...|2022-08-07T21:25:...|      4|        Certo|       null|        null|          null|
|bd46c6fb-1315-441...|2022-08-07T21:25:...|      1|Antesdevocêir|    JOHNDOE|        null|       Street1|
|14da8519-6e4c-4ed...|2022-08-07T21:25:...| 788884|        Agora|       null|        null|          null|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```